Ranger KMS - Client configuration for Kerberos authentication
We installed Ranger KMS behind a load balancer according to the following documentation:

https://hdpweb.o.onslip.net/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.0.0/installing-ranger-kms/content/install_ranger_kms_using_ambari_kerberized_cluster.html
https://hdpweb.o.onslip.net/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.0.1/configuring-hdfs-encryption/content/enabling_ssl_for_ranger_kms.html
https://hdpweb.o.onslip.net/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.0.1/configuring-hdfs-encryption/content/install_multiple_ranger_kms.html

The integration with Ranger Admin is working fine, but we are not able to authenticate from other clients such as the Hadoop CLI.
Our configurations client side:

core-site.xml

<property>
  <name>hadoop.security.key.provider.path</name>
  <value>kms://https@xxx:443/kms</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hadoop.security.kms.client.authentication.retry-count</name>
  <value>10</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hadoop.security.token.service.use_ip</name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>


kms-site.xml

<property>
  <name>hadoop.kms.authentication.type</name>
  <value>kerberos</value>
</property>

The Hadoop CLI seems not to require the Kerberos ticket for KMS:
om@xxx:~/hadoop-3.3.6/bin$ export HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGER=DEBUG,console
om@xxx:~/hadoop-3.3.6/bin$ export HADOOP_JAAS_DEBUG=true
om@xxx:~/hadoop-3.3.6/bin$ ./hadoop key list
2024-05-29 08:10:38,575 [main] DEBUG util.Shell: setsid exited with exit code 0
2024-05-29 08:10:38,759 [main] DEBUG security.SecurityUtil: Setting hadoop.security.token.service.use_ip to false
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.xbill.DNS.ResolverConfig (file:/home/om/hadoop-3.3.6/share/hadoop/common/lib/dnsjava-2.1.7.jar) to method sun.net.dns.ResolverConfiguration.open()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.xbill.DNS.ResolverConfig
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2024-05-29 08:10:38,936 [main] DEBUG ssl.SSLFactory: will exclude cipher suites:
2024-05-29 08:10:38,963 [main] DEBUG ssl.FileBasedKeyStoresFactory: The property 'ssl.client.truststore.location' has not been set, no TrustStore will be loaded
2024-05-29 08:10:39,133 [main] DEBUG kms.KMSClientProvider: KMSClientProvider created for KMS url: https://xxx:443/kms/v1/ delegation token service: kms://https@xxx:443/kms canonical service: xxx:443.
2024-05-29 08:10:39,140 [main] DEBUG kms.LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider: Created LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider for KMS url: kms://https@xxx:443/kms with 1 providers. delegation token service: kms://https@xxx:443/kms, canonical service: xxx:443
2024-05-29 08:10:39,200 [main] DEBUG lib.MutableMetricsFactory: field org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableRate org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.getGroups with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(sampleName="Ops", always=false, valueName="Time", about="", interval=10, type=DEFAULT, value={"GetGroups"})
2024-05-29 08:10:39,210 [main] DEBUG lib.MutableMetricsFactory: field org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableRate org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.loginFailure with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(sampleName="Ops", always=false, valueName="Time", about="", interval=10, type=DEFAULT, value={"Rate of failed kerberos logins and latency (milliseconds)"})
2024-05-29 08:10:39,211 [main] DEBUG lib.MutableMetricsFactory: field org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableRate org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.loginSuccess with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(sampleName="Ops", always=false, valueName="Time", about="", interval=10, type=DEFAULT, value={"Rate of successful kerberos logins and latency (milliseconds)"})
2024-05-29 08:10:39,211 [main] DEBUG lib.MutableMetricsFactory: field private org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableGaugeInt org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.renewalFailures with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(sampleName="Ops", always=false, valueName="Time", about="", interval=10, type=DEFAULT, value={"Renewal failures since last successful login"})
2024-05-29 08:10:39,212 [main] DEBUG lib.MutableMetricsFactory: field private org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableGaugeLong org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.renewalFailuresTotal with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(sampleName="Ops", always=false, valueName="Time", about="", interval=10, type=DEFAULT, value={"Renewal failures since startup"})
2024-05-29 08:10:39,215 [main] DEBUG impl.MetricsSystemImpl: UgiMetrics, User and group related metrics
2024-05-29 08:10:39,281 [main] DEBUG security.Groups:  Creating new Groups object
2024-05-29 08:10:39,284 [main] DEBUG security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping: Using JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping for Group resolution
2024-05-29 08:10:39,284 [main] DEBUG security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback: Group mapping impl=org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping
2024-05-29 08:10:39,285 [main] DEBUG security.Groups: Group mapping impl=org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback; cacheTimeout=300000; warningDeltaMs=5000
                [UnixLoginModule]: succeeded importing info:
                        uid = 1003
                        gid = 1003
                        supp gid = 1003
Debug is  true storeKey false useTicketCache true useKeyTab false doNotPrompt true ticketCache is null isInitiator true KeyTab is null refreshKrb5Config is true principal is null tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false clearPass is false
Refreshing Kerberos configuration
Acquire TGT from Cache
Principal is om/xxx@xxx
2024-05-29 08:10:39,378 [main] DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: Hadoop login
                [UnixLoginModule]: added UnixPrincipal,
                                UnixNumericUserPrincipal,
                                UnixNumericGroupPrincipal(s),
                         to Subject
Commit Succeeded

2024-05-29 08:10:39,380 [main] DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: hadoop login commit
2024-05-29 08:10:39,381 [main] DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: Using kerberos user: om/xxx@xxx
2024-05-29 08:10:39,381 [main] DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: Using user: "om/xxx@xxx" with name: om/xxx@xxx
2024-05-29 08:10:39,382 [main] DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: User entry: "om/xxx@xxx"
2024-05-29 08:10:39,382 [main] DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: UGI loginUser: om/xxx@xxx (auth:KERBEROS)
2024-05-29 08:10:39,384 [main] DEBUG kms.KMSClientProvider: Current UGI: om/xxx@xxx (auth:KERBEROS)
2024-05-29 08:10:39,385 [TGT Renewer for om/xxx@xxx] DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: Current time is 1716970239385, next refresh is 1717038526000
2024-05-29 08:10:39,391 [main] DEBUG kms.KMSClientProvider: Login UGI: om/xxx@xxx (auth:KERBEROS)
2024-05-29 08:10:39,392 [main] DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: PrivilegedAction [as: om/xxx@xxx (auth:KERBEROS)][action: org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.KMSClientProvider$1@5c45d770]
java.lang.Exception
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1896)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.KMSClientProvider.createConnection(KMSClientProvider.java:506)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.KMSClientProvider.getKeys(KMSClientProvider.java:638)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider$9.call(LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider.java:420)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider$9.call(LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider.java:417)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider.doOp(LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider.java:175)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider.getKeys(LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider.java:417)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.KeyShell$ListCommand.execute(KeyShell.java:254)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.CommandShell.run(CommandShell.java:73)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:82)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.KeyShell.main(KeyShell.java:553)
2024-05-29 08:10:39,399 [main] DEBUG web.DelegationTokenAuthenticatedURL: Connecting to url https://xxx:443/kms/v1/keys/names with token  as null
2024-05-29 08:10:39,401 [main] DEBUG web.DelegationTokenAuthenticatedURL: Token not set, looking for delegation token. Creds:[], size:0
2024-05-29 08:10:39,401 [main] DEBUG web.DelegationTokenAuthenticator: No delegation token found for url=https://xxx:443/kms/v1/keys/names, authenticating with class org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.web.KerberosDelegationTokenAuthenticator$1
2024-05-29 08:10:39,582 [main] DEBUG client.KerberosAuthenticator: Using fallback authenticator sequence.
2024-05-29 08:10:39,584 [main] DEBUG web.DelegationTokenAuthenticator: No delegation token found for url=https://xxx:443/kms/v1/keys/names, authenticating with class org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.web.PseudoDelegationTokenAuthenticator$1
2024-05-29 08:10:39,586 [main] DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: PrivilegedActionException as: om/xxx@xxx (auth:KERBEROS)
org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticationException: Error while authenticating with endpoint: https://xxx:443/kms/v1/keys/names
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.KerberosAuthenticator.wrapExceptionWithMessage(KerberosAuthenticator.java:232)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.KerberosAuthenticator.authenticate(KerberosAuthenticator.java:219)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.web.DelegationTokenAuthenticator.authenticate(DelegationTokenAuthenticator.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticatedURL.openConnection(AuthenticatedURL.java:350)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.web.DelegationTokenAuthenticatedURL.openConnection(DelegationTokenAuthenticatedURL.java:327)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.KMSClientProvider$1.run(KMSClientProvider.java:512)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.KMSClientProvider$1.run(KMSClientProvider.java:507)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1899)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.KMSClientProvider.createConnection(KMSClientProvider.java:506)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.KMSClientProvider.getKeys(KMSClientProvider.java:638)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider$9.call(LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider.java:420)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider$9.call(LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider.java:417)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider.doOp(LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider.java:175)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider.getKeys(LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider.java:417)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.KeyShell$ListCommand.execute(KeyShell.java:254)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.CommandShell.run(CommandShell.java:73)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:82)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.KeyShell.main(KeyShell.java:553)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, URL: https://xxx:443/kms/v1/keys/names?user.name=om, status: 204, message: No Content
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticatedURL.extractToken(AuthenticatedURL.java:403)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.PseudoAuthenticator.authenticate(PseudoAuthenticator.java:74)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.web.DelegationTokenAuthenticator.authenticate(DelegationTokenAuthenticator.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.KerberosAuthenticator.authenticate(KerberosAuthenticator.java:213)
        ... 18 more
2024-05-29 08:10:39,588 [main] WARN kms.LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider: KMS provider at [https://xxx:443/kms/v1/] threw an IOException:
java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticationException: Error while authenticating with endpoint: https://xxx:443/kms/v1/keys/names
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.KMSClientProvider.createConnection(KMSClientProvider.java:525)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.KMSClientProvider.getKeys(KMSClientProvider.java:638)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider$9.call(LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider.java:420)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider$9.call(LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider.java:417)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider.doOp(LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider.java:175)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider.getKeys(LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider.java:417)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.KeyShell$ListCommand.execute(KeyShell.java:254)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.CommandShell.run(CommandShell.java:73)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:82)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.KeyShell.main(KeyShell.java:553)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticationException: Error while authenticating with endpoint: https://xxx:443/kms/v1/keys/names
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.KerberosAuthenticator.wrapExceptionWithMessage(KerberosAuthenticator.java:232)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.KerberosAuthenticator.authenticate(KerberosAuthenticator.java:219)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.web.DelegationTokenAuthenticator.authenticate(DelegationTokenAuthenticator.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticatedURL.openConnection(AuthenticatedURL.java:350)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.web.DelegationTokenAuthenticatedURL.openConnection(DelegationTokenAuthenticatedURL.java:327)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.KMSClientProvider$1.run(KMSClientProvider.java:512)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.KMSClientProvider$1.run(KMSClientProvider.java:507)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1899)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.KMSClientProvider.createConnection(KMSClientProvider.java:506)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, URL: https://xxx:443/kms/v1/keys/names?user.name=om, status: 204, message: No Content
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticatedURL.extractToken(AuthenticatedURL.java:403)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.PseudoAuthenticator.authenticate(PseudoAuthenticator.java:74)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.web.DelegationTokenAuthenticator.authenticate(DelegationTokenAuthenticator.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.KerberosAuthenticator.authenticate(KerberosAuthenticator.java:213)
        ... 18 more
2024-05-29 08:10:39,591 [main] DEBUG kms.KMSClientProvider: Current UGI: om/xxx@xxx (auth:KERBEROS)
2024-05-29 08:10:39,592 [main] DEBUG kms.KMSClientProvider: Login UGI: om/xxx@xxx (auth:KERBEROS)
2024-05-29 08:10:39,592 [main] DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: PrivilegedAction [as: om/xxx@xxx (auth:KERBEROS)][action: org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.KMSClientProvider$1@6492fab5]
java.lang.Exception
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1896)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.KMSClientProvider.createConnection(KMSClientProvider.java:506)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.KMSClientProvider.getKeys(KMSClientProvider.java:638)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider$9.call(LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider.java:420)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider$9.call(LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider.java:417)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider.doOp(LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider.java:175)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider.getKeys(LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider.java:417)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.KeyShell$ListCommand.execute(KeyShell.java:254)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.CommandShell.run(CommandShell.java:73)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:82)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.KeyShell.main(KeyShell.java:553)
2024-05-29 08:10:39,592 [main] DEBUG web.DelegationTokenAuthenticatedURL: Connecting to url https://xxx:443/kms/v1/keys/names with token  as null
2024-05-29 08:10:39,593 [main] DEBUG web.DelegationTokenAuthenticatedURL: Token not set, looking for delegation token. Creds:[], size:0
2024-05-29 08:10:39,593 [main] DEBUG web.DelegationTokenAuthenticator: No delegation token found for url=https://xxx:443/kms/v1/keys/names, authenticating with class org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.web.KerberosDelegationTokenAuthenticator$1
2024-05-29 08:10:39,594 [main] DEBUG client.KerberosAuthenticator: Using fallback authenticator sequence.
2024-05-29 08:10:39,595 [main] DEBUG web.DelegationTokenAuthenticator: No delegation token found for url=https://xxx:443/kms/v1/keys/names, authenticating with class org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.web.PseudoDelegationTokenAuthenticator$1
2024-05-29 08:10:39,596 [main] DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: PrivilegedActionException as: om/xxx@xxx (auth:KERBEROS)
org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticationException: Error while authenticating with endpoint: https://xxx:443/kms/v1/keys/names
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.KerberosAuthenticator.wrapExceptionWithMessage(KerberosAuthenticator.java:232)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.KerberosAuthenticator.authenticate(KerberosAuthenticator.java:219)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.web.DelegationTokenAuthenticator.authenticate(DelegationTokenAuthenticator.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticatedURL.openConnection(AuthenticatedURL.java:350)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.web.DelegationTokenAuthenticatedURL.openConnection(DelegationTokenAuthenticatedURL.java:327)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.KMSClientProvider$1.run(KMSClientProvider.java:512)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.KMSClientProvider$1.run(KMSClientProvider.java:507)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1899)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.KMSClientProvider.createConnection(KMSClientProvider.java:506)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.KMSClientProvider.getKeys(KMSClientProvider.java:638)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider$9.call(LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider.java:420)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider$9.call(LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider.java:417)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider.doOp(LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider.java:175)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider.getKeys(LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider.java:417)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.KeyShell$ListCommand.execute(KeyShell.java:254)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.CommandShell.run(CommandShell.java:73)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:82)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.KeyShell.main(KeyShell.java:553)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, URL: https://xxx:443/kms/v1/keys/names?user.name=om, status: 204, message: No Content
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticatedURL.extractToken(AuthenticatedURL.java:403)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.PseudoAuthenticator.authenticate(PseudoAuthenticator.java:74)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.web.DelegationTokenAuthenticator.authenticate(DelegationTokenAuthenticator.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.KerberosAuthenticator.authenticate(KerberosAuthenticator.java:213)
        ... 18 more
2024-05-29 08:10:39,597 [main] WARN kms.LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider: KMS provider at [https://xxx:443/kms/v1/] threw an IOException:
java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticationException: Error while authenticating with endpoint: https://xxx:443/kms/v1/keys/names
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.KMSClientProvider.createConnection(KMSClientProvider.java:525)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.KMSClientProvider.getKeys(KMSClientProvider.java:638)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider$9.call(LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider.java:420)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider$9.call(LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider.java:417)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider.doOp(LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider.java:175)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider.getKeys(LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider.java:417)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.KeyShell$ListCommand.execute(KeyShell.java:254)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.CommandShell.run(CommandShell.java:73)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:82)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.KeyShell.main(KeyShell.java:553)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticationException: Error while authenticating with endpoint: https://xxx:443/kms/v1/keys/names
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.KerberosAuthenticator.wrapExceptionWithMessage(KerberosAuthenticator.java:232)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.KerberosAuthenticator.authenticate(KerberosAuthenticator.java:219)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.web.DelegationTokenAuthenticator.authenticate(DelegationTokenAuthenticator.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticatedURL.openConnection(AuthenticatedURL.java:350)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.web.DelegationTokenAuthenticatedURL.openConnection(DelegationTokenAuthenticatedURL.java:327)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.KMSClientProvider$1.run(KMSClientProvider.java:512)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.KMSClientProvider$1.run(KMSClientProvider.java:507)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1899)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.KMSClientProvider.createConnection(KMSClientProvider.java:506)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, URL: https://xxx:443/kms/v1/keys/names?user.name=om, status: 204, message: No Content
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticatedURL.extractToken(AuthenticatedURL.java:403)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.PseudoAuthenticator.authenticate(PseudoAuthenticator.java:74)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.web.DelegationTokenAuthenticator.authenticate(DelegationTokenAuthenticator.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.KerberosAuthenticator.authenticate(KerberosAuthenticator.java:213)
        ... 18 more
2024-05-29 08:10:39,597 [main] ERROR kms.LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider: Aborting since the Request has failed with all KMS providers(depending on hadoop.security.kms.client.failover.max.retries=1 setting and numProviders=1) in the group OR the exception is not recoverable
Cannot list keys for KeyProvider: org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider@294e5088
list [-provider <provider>] [-strict] [-metadata] [-help]:

The list subcommand displays the keynames contained within
a particular provider as configured in core-site.xml or
specified with the -provider argument. -metadata displays
the metadata. If -strict is supplied, fail immediately if
the provider requires a password and none is given.
Executing command failed with the following exception: IOException: org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticationException: Error while authenticating with endpoint: https://xxx:443/kms/v1/keys/names


The same http request returns the keys when done via curl with negotiation.

Ranger KMS is installed inside an AWS EKS, while the Ozone cluster is on virtual machines.
The authentication problem was caused by either the AWS NLB, or the Nginx ingress. We simply opened a TCP connection and everything is working fine.
